# How can I recover a lost account?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

How do I log in if my OpenID is not available, or maybe even no longer exists? Can I restore my lost account, or do I need to start over?

See also:

- [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon)
- [I lost control of my account before registering, can it be recovered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95358/i-lost-control-of-my-account-before-registering-is-it-lost-forever)

Comment: belongs on user-voice

Comment: No, it doesn't belong on uservoice.  Currently lost accounts should be e-mailed to the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page.  If you want to change how that works, put that up on uservoice.

Comment: This should be community wiki.  If there's not a FAQ item for this, there should be.  Checking now...

Comment: Okay, this is NOT in the FAQ.  I'm going to recommend that it remain open (or at least not deleted) and either the author or other users perform the necessary edits to make it community wiki and add it to the faq.

Comment: I also suggest changing to a more generic title: "How can I recover a lost StackOverflow Account?"

Comment: Added the question to the sofaq page under `Help`

Comment: @Joel, I don't know if you were a mod when you posted your initial comments, but now that you are, perhaps you'd like to FAQ-ify this yourself?

Comment: Since OpenID support was removed, the procedure has changed, and the updated process is in the answer to the FAQ [How can I log in to my Stack Exchange account if my current account provider is blocked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138994/how-can-i-log-in-to-my-stack-exchange-account-if-my-current-account-provider-is)

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is temporary, you'll simply have to wait until the OpenID is working again.

Currently *lost* accounts should be e-mailed to the 'contact us' link at the bottom of the page.  In the email, supply at least the following details:

- The full URL to your profile
- Your name (which should match the one you might have provided as "real name" in your profile)
- The email address provided in your profile, if any (you can validate that using [the recovery page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) of the site you're using, but note that an email address known to your OpenID provider might not be known to Stack Exchange as well)
- Your previous OpenID, and the reason why it needs to be replaced
- Your new OpenID

(The last 4 details are only known to you, and not publicly visible on your profile.)

To prevent this from happening in the first place, Stack Overflow supports an [alternate or backup openid](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/we-now-support-multiple-openids/) for every account, but you have to set that up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your backup provider is someone like Yahoo or Google.