# I lost control of my account before registering. Can it be recovered?

Tags: support, faq, user-accounts, unregistered-users

I asked and answered a question on a Stack Exchange site without registering. I was accessing my unregistered account through my browser, which kept me logged in. However, someone reset my cookies and now I've lost my account.

Is there a way to regain it, or should I give it up for lost?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/)

Comment: If you have a link to your account, you can write a mail to team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Gamecat - what constitutes a "link to your account"?

Comment: a link to your account page, or probably only the ID is enough. But you need to proof that its your account.

Answer (score 19):

So long as you provided us a valid email, you can simply recover your cookie by clicking the ["Forgot password" link](/users/account-recovery).

Area on the [login page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login):

[image: "Forgot password?"]

Once you have recovered your cookie, **it's strongly suggested that you click the "Sign up" link that appears on the top of every page** to convert your account from unregistered (cookie-based) to registered (login-based).

Unfortunately, if you did not provide a valid email address when you posted for the first time as an unregistered user, you cannot recover your account.