# What can I do if I can no longer access my unregistered question?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

About an hour ago I posted [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/must-a-private-institution-regularly-test-its-water-supply) under an unregistered account from my desktop. I then opened up the password email from my phone, logged in from that link, and was unable to access the question (didn't know that it would be using a cookie to keep track of everything). I panicked, figured merging with my main account could help, so I did so, and now I fear I'm forever cut off from properly editing/commenting on that question. It doesn't help that I only have 1 rep on that site.

I tried following the advice in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95358/i-lost-control-of-my-account-before-registering-can-it-be-recovered), but this only ended up in me logging into my main account (this one).

What can I do to obtain ownership of this question?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't have been so... *(puts on sunglasses)* jackfoolish. ***YEEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHH!***

Comment: Guess that's two of us whose usernames don't describe our actions ;)

Comment: On a side note, I was just granted permission to participate in meta. But this is meta. Is there a meta meta? That's meta.

Comment: @jackwise being invited to join in on meta means you can participate on a meta site where you have more than 5 reputation. ([Law meta](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: @muddyfish Yes, but I was invited to participate in the meta for *this* website.

Comment: That's strange... There isn't a meta.meta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "contact us" form at the foot of every page to request that the unregistered account be merged into your registered one.

As long as you can provide enough details to verify that you are the owner of said account (e-mail address used, IP address etc.) then the team should be able to do the honours.

Comment: Will try that, thank you!