# Using my same Google ID, logged in, and my account suddenly disappeared?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I recover a lost account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20528/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-account)

A little scared since my account suddenly disappeared. I logged in using the same Google ID I've always used, and suddenly StackOverflow created a new one for me.

I tried using the password recovery page and entered all of the known emails I've ever used (including my Google ID email) and all return "do not exist".

Suggestions are most welcome, withdrawal symptoms are setting in!

### Update

Oh boy I think I have the cause. So as of 2+ weeks ago I had to migrate my Google Apps account to a new domain (company name change) and had to delete the old account. It was only until *today* did I delete the cookies on my browser.

So in essence it's like having a whole new Google ID and I was living off of a cookie in the interim. What are the steps I can use to recover the account? Thanks!

Comment: Even if you would have copied your email address to the email field in your profile, then using http://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery would still only tell you which OpenIDs you are (were) using, so that wouldn't help anyway in this situation.

Comment: Sure as hell it wasn't a duplicate, it took some ingenuity to get my account back. Found my old iPad that still had a cookie on it and added my GoogleID. Still yet to receive response from SO team.