# How can I log in to my Stack Exchange account if I'm unable to use my current account provider?

Tags: support, faq, stack-exchange, login

I usually log in to a Stack Exchange site using another site (Google, Facebook, etc.) as my account provider.  However, I'm currently unable to use my current login provider (e.g., forgot the password to that account, in an environment where it's blocked, deleted my account on that provider, etc.).  Is there any way for me to log in to my existing Stack Exchange account even though I can't use my account provider?

[Return to the FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To prevent this situation from happening, it's recommended you add a standard email and password login and associate that to your account by following: [How do I change my login provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-login-providers).

If you are already unable to use your current login provider, you can use the form to create a new account and use the same email address while registering. Once you've verified your email address on your new account, in most cases, the new account will be automatically merged into your existing account and will have the new login method imported. In some cases (such as if you're a moderator on any site, or if the system couldn't verify something), the automatic merge will not happen; if that happens, [request that your accounts be merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous).

Comment: I've been using the Stack Exchange OpenID endpoint for just about everything lately, no problems at all. It's basically replaced MyOpenID for me.

Comment: You don't even have to bother with associating the accounts if you are using an existing "trusted“ provider like Gmail, Yahoo, etc. -just use the same email when registering, and the association will be automatic.

Comment: @Shog9: is the automagic association only for the "top" providers (SE, Google, Yahoo & Facebook right now), or all the providers that have an icon in the login page (~9 more)?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just the top ones. If you add an account and get an email address added to "my logins" then it should be trusted.

Comment: @Shog - yup, only the top verified ones we *really* trust

Comment: I'll convert this to FAQ tomorrow at some point. A lot of companies want to "take the plus out of Google"

Comment: @TimPost, that's the case here, and unfortunately Google are determined to put the plus *into* my Google profile.